# On Goldstone fermions / goldstino: SUSY breaking

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, supersymmetry, symmetry-breaking, goldstone-mode

There are statements about Goldstone fermions, or goldstino, seem confusing to me.

(1) Goldstone boson requires a **continuous symmetry spontaneously broken**. Does Goldstone fermion imply continuous SUSY spontaneously broken? But boson B and fermion F Hilbert space can be finite dimensional and discrete. The number of SUSY charge $\mathcal{N}$ is also discrete. What do we mean by **continuous SUSY** if there is ? If not, how does the **Goldstone theorem on the continuous global symmetry applies to SUSY** (possibly discrete, switching between bosonic B and fermionic F sector, and finite $\mathcal{N}$)?

(2) In [Witten 1982 NPB - Constraints on Supersymmetry Breaking](http://cds.cern.ch/record/137291), he said:

(A) the number of boson zero energy modes $n_b=0$ and fermion zero energy modes $n_f=0$ --- supersymmetry is spontaneously broken and there is a massless Goldstone fermion in the infinite volume theory.

- How and why the massless Goldstone fermion appears, only in the infinite volume limit? (only when the states of bosonic B and fermionic F sector become infinite?) How to interpret  Goldstone fermion when we have a finite size but large $L$ system?

(B) the number of boson vs fermion zero energy modes $n_b= n_f\neq 0$, supersymmetry is not broken; there is no Goldstone fermion, but there are zero-energy fermionic states which we interpret as evidence that the infinite volume theory has a massless fermion (a massless fermion is not a Goldstone fermion unless it is created from the vacuum by the supersymmetry current).

- How do we know there is a massless fermion (in the infinite volume)?
- How to show Goldstone fermion  is created from the vacuum by the supersymmetry current? (in the infinite volume? How to interpret it in the finite volume?)